# python multiprocessing : Notify parent when child gets killed

Tags: python, multiprocessing, parent-child, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to emulate a scenario where the child spawned by python multiprocessing pool gets killed. The subprocess never returns, but I would like the parent to get notified in such a scenario.The test code I am using is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import os
result_map = {}

def foo_pool(x):
    print x,' : ',os.getpid()
    pid = os.getpid()
    if x == 1:
        os.kill(pid,9)
    return x


result_list = []
def log_result(result):
    print 'callback',result


def apply_async_with_callback():
    print os.getpid()
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(2):
        result_map[i] = pool.apply_async(foo_pool, args = (i, ),     callback = log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for k,v in result_map.iteritems():
        print k,' :    ',v.successful()

    print(result_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async_with_callback()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're going the right way. If you have an event and you want to publish it, use `multiprocesing.Event`. If the child gets killed for some reason - try and install a relevant signal handler to notify the parent about the signal that killed it.

Answer (score 0):

The Pool of processes does not expose any mechanism to notify the parent process about a child process termination.

Projects like [billiard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/billiard/) or [pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble/3.1.9) might do what you're looking for.

Keep in mind that there's no way to intercept a SIGKILL signal so using signal handlers is pointless.

Comment: Using signal handlers is pointless in the child, but not in the parent, which can use `SIGCHLD` to find out if a child terminated for any reason.

Comment: SIGCHLD is not supported by all OSes. Moreover many Unix implementations of SIGCHLD tend to aggregate multiple signals making harder to detect which process died and when.

Comment: @noxdafox wait() tells you which child died.

Comment: wait() is not portable as it's not supported on Windows. Moreover Python does not expose such API for processes.